# How to extract elements of li one by one?

Tags: php, preg-match-all, data-extraction

How to extract elements of li one by one ?
Example: the value of date is "03 february 2016", the value of year is "2008" and so on.

**No** 
        269812985

**Date** 
            
                03 february 2016

**Marka** 
                BMW

**Seri** 
                5 Serisi

**Model** 
                530xd

**Year** 
                
                    2008

The html code is:

```html
    <ul class="classifiedInfoList"> 
        <li> 
            <strong>No</strong>&nbsp; 
            <span class="classifiedId" id="classifiedId">269812985</span> 
        </li> 
        <li> 
            <strong> date</strong>&nbsp; 
            <span> 03 february 2016</span> 
        </li> 
        <li> 
            <strong>Marka</strong>&nbsp; 
            <span>BMW&nbsp;</span> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <strong>Seri</strong>&nbsp; 
            <span>5 Serisi&nbsp;</span>
        </li>
        <li> 
            <strong>Model</strong>&nbsp; 
            <span>530xd&nbsp;</span>
        </li> 
        <li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: the html code is:  <ul class="classifiedInfoList">
    <li>
        <strong>No</strong>&nbsp;
        <span class="classifiedId" id="classifiedId">269812985</span>
        </li>
    <li>
            <strong>
               date</strong>&nbsp;
            <span>
                03 february 2016</span>
        </li>
    <li>
                <strong>Marka</strong>&nbsp;
                <span>BMW&nbsp;</span>
        </li><li<strong>Seri</strong>&nbsp;
                <span>5 Serisi&nbsp;</span></li><li>
<strong>Model</strong>&nbsp;
          <span>530xd&nbsp;</span></li> <li></ul>

Comment: Please check:- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask     and format your question accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Abdoulaye! Unfortunately your question is unsuitable for this site. We'll be happy to help you with the specific problems you encounter while programming your stuff, but you have to **add more details** and **show more relevant code.** **You can edit questions using ‘edit’ link below tags list.** Please see **“[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”** for more information.